# Create different instance of a React component in React Router with import

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux, reactjs-flux

I am trying to initiate to use the same component but passing diffrent props to it depending on the route. Like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from "react-router";

import Layout from "./pages/Layout";
import ApplicantsContainer from "./pages/ApplicantsContainer";
import Filtered from "./pages/Filtered";
import ApplicantStore from "./stores/ApplicantStore";

const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
      <IndexRoute/>
      <Route path="new" component={ApplicantsContainer} getData={ApplicantStore.getNew.bind(ApplicantStore)}/>
      <Route path="prescreen" component={ApplicantsContainer} getData={ApplicantStore.getPrescreen.bind(ApplicantStore)}/>
      <Route path="interview" component={ApplicantsContainer} getData={ApplicantStore.getInterview.bind(ApplicantStore)}/>
      <Route path="offer" component={ApplicantsContainer} getData={ApplicantStore.getOffer.bind(ApplicantStore)}/>
      <Route path="hired" component={ApplicantsContainer} getData={ApplicantStore.getHired.bind(ApplicantStore)}/>
      <Route path="declined" component={ApplicantsContainer} getData={ApplicantStore.getDeclined.bind(ApplicantStore)}/>
      <Route path="filtered" component={Filtered}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
app);
```

The problem is all routes receives the same instance of the component and use only the first getData props. How to declare different instances of the **ApplicantsContainer** component?

Comment: Cannot find "getData" property for <Route> at react-router API https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md. Where did you get it? And how you can use it at components?

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a new component outside `<Router/>`

e.g. your version

```
<Route path="new" component={ApplicantsContainer} 
    getData={ApplicantStore.getNew.bind(ApplicantStore)}/>
<Route path="prescreen" component={ApplicantsContainer}
    getData={ApplicantStore.getPrescreen.bind(ApplicantStore)}/>
```

can be rewritten to

```
 // Assume getData is a prop you need to set in ApplicantsContainer
const ApplicantsContainerForNew = (
  <ApplicantsContainer
    getData={ApplicantStore.getNew.bind(ApplicantStore)}
  />
)

const ApplicantsContainerForPrescreen = (
  <ApplicantsContainer
   getData={ApplicantStore.getPrescreen.bind(ApplicantStore)}
  />
)
...

<Route path="new" component={ApplicantsContainerForNew}/>
<Route path="prescreen" component={ApplicantsContainerForPrescreen} />
```